# implementing my first PHP model

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, architecture, model

I've written a small RESTful PHP backend using the Slim framework (http://www.slimframework.com/) that interfaces with a MySQL database, and right now I just have one class doing all the DB interactions and it's getting kinda big. So it's time to organize it a little more cleanly.

So based on what I understand from MVC, a better way to do this might be to implement a model layer like so:

- each logical entity in the system will be implemented with a data class. I.E. user accounts: a class called "Account" with getId(), getName(), getEmail(), etc etc
- and corresponding factory objects, i.e. AccountFactory which owns the DB connection and creates an Account class to manipulate elsewhere in the business logic layer.
- The business logic layer would still be pretty simple, maybe a class called MyApplication that instantiates factories and uses them to respond to the RESTful API calls.
- Business logic might be, for example, matching two accounts together based on geographical location. So in this case, I would just be testing on the data in two separate Account objects instead of the raw data loaded from the database.

But that seems like a lot of refactoring time spent to do basically the same thing. Why wouldn't I want to just use the plain array data I load from the database? It's not DB-independent, sure, but I don't really plan on switching away from MySQL at the moment anyway.

Am I approaching this in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Well, partly.

The first point describes a model - the M in MVC. Abstracting your "business logic" from this model makes sense in many ways. One use case could be a website that interacts with the same data as the REST API. You could reuse the model and only need to build new controllers.

The "business logic"/"layer" would probably the controller - the C in MVC. However I would not give the factory objects ownership of the DB connection, as some use cases may want to use multiple factory objects but should use the same database connection...

I suggest you read more about the structure and pro's and con's of the MVC approach.

Answer (score -1):

when you start from scratch the best is to :

- have a ORM (which mean that you must have relations in your MySQL database with foreign keys etc.). Thats very quick way to manage database management in your program.
- Create your home-made class for each entitiy = 1 class.

The best pratices are generally to have an ORM but it can be a bit heavy (it depends on your architecture and application).
In your case put an ORM seems to be a lot too much cause you developped a lot.
It depends of the future of your application : will it grow again ? will a lot of developper will develop on it ?

For a small/medium size you can easily refactor a bit your class by big theme, ex : 1 class for your 3 biggest entity in which you have the more requests. That will tidy a bit the mess and organize things, and then you can migrate your new classes for eqch new entity. For the old ones you can migrate step by stepm or not

Another good practice is to have getters and setters `$this->getter_id();` `$this->setter_id( $in_nId );` That will help you a lot if you need to change some db fields